# Find Address From Coordinates

Tags: flutter

```dart
final addresses =
        await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromCoordinates(coordinates);
    selectedAddress = addresses.first;
```

> The plugin `geocoder` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
> To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
> If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.

Comment: Can you mention the plugin version which you are using?

Comment: Use this plugin geocoding instead of geocoder

Answer (score 1):

Use `[geolocator][1]` package and write the below code to get the city name and coordinates

```
void main() async {
  await configureInjection(Environment.dev);
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  Position _currentPosition = await getCurrentPosition();

  List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
      _currentPosition.latitude, _currentPosition.longitude);

  Placemark place = placemarks[0];

  runApp(AppWidget());
}

Future<Position> getCurrentPosition() async {
  bool serviceEnabled;
  LocationPermission permission;

  serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
  if (!serviceEnabled) {
    return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
  }

  permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }

  if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
    // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
    return Future.error(
        'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
  }

  return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
  );
}
```